# Using Background Music while playing game on Android app game

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie in Android Developer
I am building a game app on Android Studio. But, I have had a problem about Background music while playing game. I have used **Bound Service** to handle through the class: MusicService extends Service  implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener. But, my App was stopped when I run. 
I have tried to fixed and explored solutions, but, I can't run app...
This is source code:

**MusicService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicService extends Service  implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private int length = 0;
    public MediaPlayer Player;


    public MusicService() {
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        }


        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                    extra) {

                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and, **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean mIsBound = false;
    private MusicService mServ;
    private ServiceConnection Scon =new ServiceConnection(){
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.ServiceBinder binder = (MusicService.ServiceBinder)service;
            mServ =binder.getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mServ = null;
        }
    };

    // Activity create UI its
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    // Activity start.
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // create Intent for MusicService.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MusicService.class);
        // call method bindService(..) to bind activity
        this.bindService(intent, Scon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    //Activity stop
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mIsBound) {
            this.unbindService(Scon);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
```

Then, I didn't also forget add the code following in AndroidManifest

```
<service
            android:name=".MusicService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
```

That's all problems mine. This makes me so confuse
Help you, please
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Can you add more log debug in logcat? Not sure but I guess problem is you call:

```
 mPlayer.start();
```

in onStartComand(). Your service should implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener and above function should be call in

```
void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
```